# Ruby/Rails: best way of checking if a User has an Answer for a Q

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a method in my User model that tries to determine if a user has answered a Question. A User `has_many` Answers, and a Question `has_many` Answers (`through` Choices). Here's what I have so far:

```
  def has_answered(question)
    has_answered_question = false
    answers.each { |answer| 
      has_answered_question = true if answer.question == question
    }
    has_answered_question
  end
```

I was wondering if there's any way to clean this up. It seems like there should be someway to do this without a boolean, and possibly in less lines than I'm currently doing it. The more suggestions / ways of doing this, the better. All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answers.any? { |answer|  answer.question == question }
```

or

```
Answer.where('user_id = ?', user.id).where('question_id = ?', question.id).limit(1).count > 0
```

Comment: I should note that this falls under the `N + 1` query antipattern... probably not recommended for big scale use :)

Comment: This sometimes fails for N + 1...  not if you include the model in your query.  Either way you can do...  

Answer.where('user_id = ?', user.id).where('question_id = ?', question.id).count > 0